# Prestashop Tools::getValue() function do not escape sql injection?

Tags: php, sql, prestashop, code-injection

I read in prestashop forum that the function `Tools::getValue()` do not escape sql injection. Now I wonder how I can prevent this function from sql injection when I want to get string or int value?

Can somebody show me example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Tools::getValue()` only retrieves POST or GET value.

To prevent SQL injection you can use `pSQL()` function or for int values you can do typecasting.

```
 $int_val = (int)Tools::getValue('someValue');
 $string_val = pSQL(Tools::getValue('someValue'));
```

Comment: Thanks, It is very helpful for me, now I know how to make safer Presta for me.